# Determining if two groups of uneven size have the same distribution?

Tags: distributions, frequency

I have two groups, an experimental of ~100 and a control group ~1000. I want to pick a selection of 100 from the control group at random to be the proper control for the experimental group.

Before I do that, though, I want to ensure the control group has the same characteristics as the experimental. (IE- do the people in the control group have the same distributions for education level- hs, undergraduate, graduate so they are discrete variables)

What sort of statistical test would I run for this to determine distribution "similarity in frequency"? i have spss, stata, and r for tools.

Thank you

Comment: Because not using all of the control group loses power (considerably), could you explain what you hope to gain by this procedure?

Comment: hello! we want to determine if we take a random sample from the control, it will be adequately matched to the experimental group. Thus, i want to see if the distributions of certain characteristics (eg, education, insurance) are similarly distributed between the two groups

Comment: But why?  This won't be an effective way to analyze your experimental data, unless there are problems with the control group that cause it not to be representative. And if that's the case, what to do about them depends on the nature of those problems.

Comment: right. So  this step is to determine if theyre similar enough , if that makes sense